# Replace lambda expression in MongoDB query with Func

Tags: c#, mongodb, lambda, func

I would like to replace the lambda expression in the following code

```
var idQuery = Query<ApiStatisticsAggregatedStats>.EQ(t => t.Api, id);
```

with a func. Hovering over the statement it says the declaration is

```
Func<ApiStatisticsAggregatedStats, string>
```

The following code gives an error though,

```
Func<ApiStatisticsAggregatedStats, string> idFunc = x => x.Api
var idQuery = Query<ApiStatisticsAggregatedStats>.EQ(idFunc, id);
```

Error:

> The best overloaded method match for `Query<ApiStatisticsAggregatedStats>.EQ<string>(Expression<Func<ApiStatisticsAggregatedStats, IEnumerable<string>>>, string)` has some invalid arguments.

Where did that `IEnumerable` come from? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for cleaning up the post. However, that error section you did truncated the message since the "less-than" characters were removed.

Comment: Sorry 'bout that - fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Query providers, like mongoDB query provider, use expression trees instead of delegates. That's why you have to declare your variable as

```
Expression<Func<ApiStatisticsAggregatedStats, string>> idFunc = x => x.Api
```

You can still assign a lambda expression to `Expression<Func<...>>` variable, because compiler can transform your lambda into proper method calls from `Expression` class during compilation.

> When a lambda expression is assigned to a variable of type `Expression<TDelegate>`, the compiler emits code to build an expression tree that represents the lambda expression.

However, it works for single-line lambdas only.

> The C# and Visual Basic compilers can generate expression trees only from expression lambdas (or single-line lambdas). It cannot parse statement lambdas (or multi-line lambdas).

If you'd try doing following:

```
Expression<Func<ApiStatisticsAggregatedStats, string>> idFunc = x => { return x.Api };
```

(notice `{` and `}`) you'd get compile error saying compiler is not able to transform multi-line lambda into expression tree.

Bot quotes come from [Expression Trees (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx).

Comment: Awesome. Worked wonders. I had tried to assign the Func to an Expression, which compiled but failed at runtime. Guess it's time to properly read through the section on expression trees in C# in Depth.